# Questionnaire Restrictions in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 10 question questionnaire. I want to restrict the answer to one box chosen with an "X".  I have already coded the "X" input restrictions via DATA VALIDATION.  Now I need to restrict the # of answers per question to just one:

THE "X" will appear on the left of the question.

```
Test Question                           
    Answer 1                        
    Answer 2                        
    Answer 3                        
    Answer 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using controls. [Here is a good article on how to use controls.](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?151) An *option* or *radio* button would be perfect for your scenario.